# public posts accessible to comments on facebook

Tags: facebook

I don't think this is what the OP was asking. I have noticed that for some people who I'm not friends with, I can like their photos, but for others I can't (even though I can view them in both cases). I can't find any setting to control this though

I have this same problem, did you ever find out how it is done. I have stuff on public and people comment on them but I see others who have their pics on public but as a non friend of theirs i can't comment. Why is this?

Comment: Who is the OP you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that, the non-friends's posts you'd see that you can't comment on were shared with 'friends only' and your friends activity on them could put these posts in your newsfeed. You could still like these posts anyway. The ones you could comment on were shared with 'friends of friends' or 'public'.

These settings are now gone and you have a different set of options under audience, which is accessible from the privacy tab. The new settings among others include public, only you, friends, acquaintances, friends except acquaintances, etc. You can also access these on the post editor. Friends except acquaintances might be the one you can't comment on.